# Find the number of digits in a number

Tags: shell, sh

Here I have written a shell script program which uses a while loop to find the number of digits in 'n', which is 23. However I get the error "23: command not found". Here's the code:

```
n=23
 
sd=0
 
# store number of digit 
nd=0
on=$n # store $n so that we can use it later
 
# use while loop to caclulate the number of digit
while [$n -gt 0]
do
    sd=$(( $n % 10 )) # get Remainder 
    n=$(( $n / 10 )) 
    nd=$(( $nd + 1))
echo  "Number of digit in a $on is $nd"
done
```

Comment: You need a space between the `[` and `]` and the conditionals in the expression (`while [ $n -gt 0 ]`). Because there's no space you're trying to execute a command named `[23`.

Comment: You know you could just `echo ${#n}`, right?

Comment: @ObwervantMagic: I'm pretty sure that the error message was not _23: command not found_, but _[23: command not found_ . Always be careful when copying an error message.